# How to display the last record from the table with remaining records?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. I have a two table and I am joining than using join.

members

```
 member_id | name  | email       
        1  |lkjh   |asd@gmail.com
        2  |jjlk   |qwe@gmail.com
        3  |sfsd   |gfh@gmail.com
        4  |qqwe   |tyut@gmail.com
```

member_details

```
id | member_id |game   | year     | date_of_added
1  |   1       |lkjh   |2018-2019 | 14-02-2019 02:26:30
2  |   1       |jjlk   |2019-2020 | 14-02-2019 03:30:20
3  |   2       |sfsd   |2018-2019 | 14-02-2019 04:00:40
4  |   3       |qqwe   |2018-2019 | 14-02-2019 04:30:20
5  |   2       |sfsd   |2019-2020 | 14-02-2019 05:45:30
```

Now my issue is, I have to display all the records from the member_details but I have to display the last records of the member_id.

So my expected output from member_details table is,

```
   1   |jjlk   |2019-2020 | 14-02-2019 03:30:20
   3   |qqwe   |2018-2019 | 14-02-2019 04:30:20
   2   |sfsd   |2019-2020 | 14-02-2019 05:45:30
```

I tried below code

```
$get_s_member = array('members.is_Approved'=>1,'members.is_status'=>1);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('members'); 
    $this->db->join('membership_details', 'members.member_id = membership_details.member_id','LEFT');
    $this->db->where($get_s_member);
    $this->db->group_by('membership_details.member_id'); 
    $this->db->order_by('membership_details.date_of_added','DESC');
     $this->db->limit('1');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $res   = $query->result();
 return $res;
```

Comment: why do you add limit ?

Comment: @M.Hemant, I thought, It will display my expected output but later I realized that it will display only one record.

Comment: @M.Hemant, I have more than 100 records in the table. Are you sure I have to use limit('3'). I have doubt in this

Comment: no, this won't work.

Comment: what if you remove  $this->db->limit('1'); line ?

Comment: @M.Hemant, oh! That I haven't tried. give me time to check.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*, t2.* from 
member_details t1
join member 
on t1.member_id = t2.member_id
where (t1.member_id, t1.date_of_added) in
      (select member_id, max(date_of_added)
       from member_details
       group by member_id
      )
```

Comment: Let me try, give me some time to check

Comment: Why member table is missing?

Comment: you've all the column in `member_details` table that you want to show in result. That's why i didn't use `member` table.

Comment: No, I have two different tables. I forgot to change the column name in member_details. I updated my column name.

Comment: Give me time to check

Comment: Oh I'll surely add the description once op confirms that it's working or not as i hadn't tested it yet.

Comment: Actually, I am not able to understand how to convert your query in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$get_s_member = array('members.is_Approved'=>1,'members.is_status'=>1);
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('membership_details'); 
$this->db->join('members', 'membership_details.member_id = members.member_id','LEFT');
$this->db->where($get_s_member);
$this->db->group_by('membership_details.member_id'); 
$this->db->order_by('membership_details.date_of_added','DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
$res   = $query->result();
return $res;
```

Comment: can you explain to me. where I have to change in my code?

Comment: Select from membership_details table and join members table, instead of select from members table and join membership_details

Comment: Can you explain to me why you interchange the table... it will be more helpful for me.

Comment: why you interchange the table instead of join type, either you can change Right Join too